# Cat output different from redirect output

Tags: linux, unix, redirect, encoding, cat

I have a ".msg" file, and I wanted to do some textual parsing on it. I have not installed any package to convert a .msg file to any other kind of format.

When I do :

`cat testing.msg`  <--- Shows up correctly and whatever in the screen is what I want

However when I do:

`cat testing.msg > file`   <---- The file seems to be encoded when I do vi and look into the file.

`testing.msg`: CDF V2 Document, No summary info

How can I correctly to read the msg file so that I get the correct textual data?

I have tried changing the `$LANG` variables but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do "cat file". Is it the same output than "cat testing.msg"?

Comment: You can compare your files using "diff testing.msg file"

Also you can use colordiff.